# Remove all characters before special character in android

Tags: java, regex, string

I have to remove `##` before `$$` from string `##$$abxcyhshbhs##xcznbx##`. I am using:

```
string.split("\\#");
```

The problem is that it also removes `#` after `$$`.

Comment: use `indexOf("$")` and `substring(startIndex,endIndex)` methods to achieve this

Comment: Can there be more than 2 `#`s before `$$`? Can they appear not just at the beginning of the string? If yes, try [this code](https://ideone.com/SPgdIN).

Answer (score 2):

Use replace() instead.

```
String text = "##$$abxcyhshbhs##xcznbx##";
text = text.replace("##$$", "$$");
```

Comment: Your code was wrong because OP needs to remove ## before $$, not $$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring method like below

string.substring(2);

Answer (score 0):

To literally remove the first two characters, use the following:

```
String s = "##$$abxcyhshbhs##xcznbx##";
s.substring(2, s.length());
```

This doesn't do any pattern matching to look for the `$$`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use String.split() you can do what you want by limiting the number of results by doing:

```
String str = "##$$abxcyhshbhs##xcznbx##";
str = str.split("##", 2)[1];
```

I don't know your exact issue but as has already been said, replace() or substring() is probably a better option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have unknown number of `#` symbols before `$$` and  they appear not just at the beginning of the string, you can use the following `replaceAll` with a regex:

```
String re = "#+\\${2}"; 
String str = "##$$abxcyh###$$shbhs##xcznbx##"; 
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(re, "\\$\\$")); // Note escaped $ !!!
// => $$abxcyh$$shbhs##xcznbx##
// or
re = "#+(\\${2})";  // using capturing and back-references
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(re, "$1"));
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/SPgdIN).

Do not forget to assign the variable a new value when using in your code:

```
str = str.replaceAll("#+(\\${2})", "$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to remove `##` from first occurrence of `##$$` in the string, then following code snippet will be helpful:

```
if(yourString.startsWith("##$$")){
     yourString.replaceFirst("##$$","$$");
}
```

OR considering there is only single `$$` in your string, following would be helpful:

```
String requiredString="";
String[] splitArr = yourString.split("\\$");
if ( splitArr.length > 1 ) {
    requiredString = "$$" + splitArr[splitArr.length-1];
}
```

I have written a code snippet [here](http://goo.gl/1kTcBh). You can make changes and execute on your own.